# Unable to install edgeDriver via DISM

Tags: webdriver, microsoft-edge

Running the appropriate command:

DISM.exe /Online /Add-Capability /CapabilityName:Microsoft.WebDriver~~~~0.0.1.0

is now returning this and not installing.  How do I get that capability back?

```
Deployment Image Servicing and Management tool
Version: 10.0.17134.1967

Image Version: 10.0.17134.2145
Error: 87

A Windows capability name was not recognized.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the information you provide, it seems that you're using Edge version 17. The command only works for Edge Legacy version 18 or higher. Please check for the latest Windows 10 updates and install them to get the newer version of Edge.

Besides, the command only works for Edge Legacy. If you want to download Edge WebDriver for Edge Chromium, please download them on [this page](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/tools/webdriver/).